# Perform Math operations on previous and current row value in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a requirement wherein I need to perform few mathematical calculations on the previous and current value of a column in Snowflake.

For eg:

My Snowflake table has data like below

[image]

Here CHANGE_IN_FRUIT_COUNT and CHANGE_IN_VEG_COUNT fields are calculated as below

((current_val/previous_val)*100)-100

I would like to implement the same logic in my table as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    date,
    fruits_sold,
    vegetable_sold,
    lag(vegetable_sold) over (order by date) as prev_vegetable_sold,
    lag(fruits_sold) over (order by date) as prev_fruits_sold,
    ((vegetable_sold/prev_vegetable_sold)*100)-100 as change_in_veg_count,
    ((fruits_sold/prev_fruits_sold)*100)-100 as change_in_fruit_count
    
FROM VALUES
    ('2022-01-01'::date, 18, 11)
    ,('2022-01-02'::date, 20, 16)
    ,('2022-01-03'::date, 25, 40)
    ,('2022-01-04'::date, 12, 14)
    ,('2022-01-05'::date, 18, 6)
    d(date, fruits_sold, vegetable_sold);
```

gives:

| DATE | FRUITS_SOLD | VEGETABLE_SOLD | PREV_VEGETABLE_SOLD | PREV_FRUITS_SOLD | CHANGE_IN_VEG_COUNT | CHANGE_IN_FRUIT_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 18 | 11 |  |  |  |  |
| 2022-01-02 | 20 | 16 | 11 | 18 | 45.4545 | 11.1111 |
| 2022-01-03 | 25 | 40 | 16 | 20 | 150 | 25 |
| 2022-01-04 | 12 | 14 | 40 | 25 | -65 | -52 |
| 2022-01-05 | 18 | 6 | 14 | 12 | -57.1429 | 50 |

which shows how the [LAG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lag.html) is used to get prior value. And if you really don't need to reuse the value for other things, you can bundle it into a single line as Lukasz has shown:

```
SELECT 
    date,
    ((vegetable_sold/lag(vegetable_sold) over (order by date))*100)-100 change_in_veg_count,
    ((fruits_sold/lag(fruits_sold) over (order by date))*100)-100 change_in_fruit_count
FROM VALUES
    ('2022-01-01'::date, 18, 11)
    ,('2022-01-02'::date, 20, 16)
    ,('2022-01-03'::date, 25, 40)
    ,('2022-01-04'::date, 12, 14)
    ,('2022-01-05'::date, 18, 6)
    d(date, fruits_sold, vegetable_sold);
```

| DATE | CHANGE_IN_VEG_COUNT | CHANGE_IN_FRUIT_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 |  |  |
| 2022-01-02 | 45.4545 | 11.1111 |
| 2022-01-03 | 150 | 25 |
| 2022-01-04 | -65 | -52 |
| 2022-01-05 | -57.1429 | 50 |

Answer (score 1):

Using LAG:

```
SELECT DATE, 
   (FRUITS_SOLD / LAG(FRUITS_SOLD) 
                      OVER(ORDER BY DATE))*100-100 AS CHANGE_IN_FRUIT_COUNT.
   (VEGETABLE_SOLD / LAG(VEGETABLE_SOLD ) 
                      OVER(ORDER BY DATE))*100-100 AS CHANGE_IN_VEG_COUNT
FROM tab
ORDER BY DATE;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d3d41b04bba248d98242e31eed16f0c8)**